# Como terminar un Service desde un Activity

Tags: android, android-service

Código de mi servicio.

```
public class ServiceMessage extends Service{

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("onServiceMessage", "El servicio ha comenzado");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    Log.d("onServiceMessage", "Servicio funcionando...");
                     try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("onServiceMessage", "El servicio ha terminado");
    }

}
```

Desde mi activity lo inicio de la siguiente forma:

```
startService(new Intent(this, ServiceMessage.class));
```

Y lo termino de la siguiente forma:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, ServiceMessage.class));
```

Cuando lo termino con `stopService()`, en el Logcat sí aparece el mensaje que dice **El servicio ha terminado**, sin embargo después vuelve a aparecer el mensaje **El servicio ha comenzado** y posteriormente **Servicio funcionando**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para detener el servicio es precisamente como lo realizas:

```
stopService(new Intent(this, ServiceMessage.class));
```

el "problema" aquí es que en tu servicio estas definiendo [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

> [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

cambia a [START_NOT_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY)

> [START_NOT_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY) : El sistema operativo no recreara el servicio
>   si la aplicación se destruye.